# How to create new .clj files in Eclipse?

Tags: clojure

I am very new to Clojure and just installed CounterClockWise and created my first Clojure project in Eclipse.

However I need to create another .clj file aside from the provided core clojure file.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *New File* command in Eclipse which can be used to create an empty file of any type. If you create a file and name it `something.clj` you have a new Clojure file.

The *New File* command can be accessed through the menus like this:

*File* menu *> New > Other... > General > File*

Or with a keyboard shortcut: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open the *New* wizard, then type `file` in the search box to filter out the file creation command.

This technique is very useful generally to create various new things.

---

Maybe there also is a *New Clojure File* command (or something like that) in the list of things in the *New* wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Not an Eclipse answer, but I sometimes have a similar issue with IDEA.  The simplest answer (on linux) is to just do `touch src/myproj/newfile.clj` or similar, to create an empty file with the desired name and location. The IDE can then easily open the (pre-existing) file for further editing.

A similar strategy is to open the file for the 1st time in another editor like vi, emacs, or whatever.

---

A related issue on IDEA is that it uses the namespace declaration `(ns xyz ...)` to label the editor tab, not the actual file name.  If you are renaming files you cannot actually see the new name easily until you change the ns declaration, which is very confusing.  In these cases, I will also fall back to using `gvim` to edit the `ns` declaration, or any other low-level or detailed edits.

Comment: I would be really surprised, if Cursive is throwing all the thinge, that are there in plain IDEA out of the window.  E.g. Alt-Insert to create a new namespace'd file and complaining at an `ns`-vs-file-location mismatch and allow to fix it easily with Alt-Enter (move file or fix ns)